# How to fix the fatal error due to cached data while migrating?

Tags: 7, caching, migrations

I was trying to migrate my site from one computer to another. I have imported .sql file from database from my first database (unfortunately forgot to clear cache) and created a new database in the second and exported the data. Then i have tried to point the settings.php's database array to the newly created database in the second computer but when i tried to access the page, i get a white screen with the following error

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/sites/pullup.local/modules/remote_stream_wrapper/remote_stream_wrapper.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3186

Where **sites/pullup.local** was my site folder in the first computer which is not present here. Then i tried to remove all the entries in the database starting with "cache". Even after clearing all the entries in the cache tables i am getting same error and I am not understanding that from where old folder path coming.

I also tried to remove the database entry from settings.php then it is working normal as the web installation page coming up. So I think something caches the old folder in the database (DRUPAL_ROOT variable value is cached).

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal uses code registry to load the files containing a class or an interface. While the code registry is cached in cache_bootstrap, it is contained in the *registry* and *registry_file* database tables.

To rebuild it, I would edit those database tables to change the path shown in the *filename* row to match the new site's path. Other methods that require bootstrapping Drupal would probably not work, since any class Drupal would use would not be found, causing a PHP exception, and stopping the bootstrap, with the effect that Drupal would not run the necessary code.

Comment: Worked perfectly after changing all the paths in the registry and registry_file tables.  Thanks a lot